# Test redirect using @user_passes_test decorator

Tags: django, django-views

My view file has:

```
def is_authorised(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='bookkeepers').exists()

@login_required
def unauthorised(request):
    context = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'order_book/unauthorised.html', context)

@login_required
@user_passes_test(is_authorised,
                  login_url='/order_book/unauthorised/',
                  redirect_field_name=None)
def book(request):
    return render(request, 'order_book/book.html', {})
```

I want to write a test asserting that a logged in user who is not authorised does get redirected correctly, so far I have this:

```
class RestrictedViewsTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):  # noqa
        """Set up data for the whole TestCase."""
        User.objects.create_user(username='JaneDoe',
                                 email='jane.doe@example.com',
                                 password='s3kr3t')

    def setUp(self):
        auth = self.client.login(username='JaneDoe', password='s3kr3t')
        self.assertTrue(auth)

    def test_book(self):
        response = self.client.get('/order_book/book')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 301, response)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(response, HttpResponsePermanentRedirect))

    def tearDown(self):
        self.client.logout()
```

This works fine as it is but I cannot fathom where to get the redirected to url. Trying to get `response['Location']` gives me '/order_book/book' which is not right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you add the missing slash to the end of the url in `self.client.get('/order_book/book/')`, then I think `response['Location']` should give you `/order_book/unauthorised/` as you expect. However I recommend you use the `assertRedirects` method in my answer.

Comment: @Alasdair As soon as the typo was fixes, the redirect code is back to being 302 which is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) method.

```
def test_book(self):
    response = self.client.get('/order_book/book/')
    self.assertRedirects(response, '/order_book/unauthorised/', status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

Comment: After change the status code to 301, I get: `AssertionError: Couldn't retrieve redirection page '/order_book/book/': response code was 302 (expected 200)`… ☹

Comment: You are missing a slash on the end of `/order_book/book` - Django is currently redirecting from `/order_book/book` to `/order_book/book/` to `/order_book/unauthorised/`.

Comment: Err… I feel sheepish now ☺ Thank you.

Comment: Easy mistake to miss - I didn't spot it when I first answered your question.